# What is lifetime of Flask-RESTPlus Resource class?

Tags: flask-restplus, flask-restx

Basically I need to know whether I can use `@functools.cached_property` in a Flask-RESTPlus `Resource` subclass to cache an expensive operation or collaborator construction that should not survive beyond a single request.

I'm thinking there are two possibilities:

1. A `Resource` subclass instance is created fresh for each HTTP request routed to that resource.
2. A `Resource` subclass instance is created once when an API is constructed and reused for every request routed to that resource for the lifetime of the API.

Caching on the object/instance would only work in Case 1. `@cached_property` is in effect a lazyily-computed instance variable, its value computed on first use and stored in an instance variable, then served from that variable on each successive access/call. I expect the mechanism is actually a descriptor, but the concept is the same.

In any case, I need a different value for each request, I just need to use it multiple times in the course of processing a single request and I need the value to be computed exactly once for that request.

Will `@cached_property` work the way I need on a Flask-RESTPlus `Resource` subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An instance of the `Resource` class is created for each request. You can quickly verify by creating a breakpoint in its `__init__()` method.

Also, consider using the [Flask.g](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.g) namespace object. It has the lifetime of a request context and is typically used to store db connections, etc that need to be created once per request and destroyed after the request ends.